# Append from one list to a 2d list - haskell

Tags: haskell

I want a function where I pass in a list of lists and a list eg `[[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,12,7]]` and `[4,5,6]`

and the function should return a list of lists with every item from the second list appended to the end of the first list

eg the output will be `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[9,12,7,5],[9,12,7,6],[9,12,7,4],[5,6,3,4],[5,6,3,5],[5,6,3,6]]`

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, like

```
Prelude> x = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,12,7]]
Prelude> y = [4,5,6]
Prelude> (flip (++) . return) <$> y <*> x
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,3,4],[9,12,7,4],[1,2,3,5],[5,6,3,5],[9,12,7,5],[1,2,3,6],[5,6,3,6],[9,12,7,6]]
```

You can think `<$>` as the infix `fmap`, `<*>` as cartesian product.

or list comprehension

```
Prelude> [ a ++ [b] | a <- x, b <- y ]
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[5,6,3,4],[5,6,3,5],[5,6,3,6],[9,12,7,4],[9,12,7,5],[9,12,7,6]]
```

or with `do` syntax

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
f ys xs = do
    y <- ys
    x <- xs
    return $ x ++ return y

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let x = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,12,7]]
    let y = [4,5,6]
    print $ f y x
```

---

For more information, you can refer to

1. http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids
2. http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads